# Mobile apps social Oauth

Tags: web-application, mobile, android, oauth, authorization

I need to develop `iOS` and `Android` apps that should have to communicate with a server throught `RESTfull API`. Also I need to register and authorize user throught popular social networks like Facebook, Twitter, Google.

What is the best scenario of doing that? For example: I generate `access_token` in my mobile app and then sending it to the server like `example.com/auth?google?<access_token>`. Could somebody stole my `access_token` then get access to the user's personal info or to the user's account?

Comment: I'm having trouble following your question. How will the access token be used? Where did it come from?

Comment: Have you looked at examples for integrating with those services? You can find many good examples and maybe even a library to support you in that.

Comment: @NeilSmithline, it generates in mobile app after user has been authorized thought Oauth and then used on the server to register or authorize user by and allows to get user's info from that social network

Comment: @NeilSmithline, yes I do, but i didn't find useful information

Comment: I'm sorry Near, but I still don't follow. How is the access token generated? How does the server validate it? What data does it contain? How can it be trusted?

Comment: access_token generated by the SDK that provides authorization by social networks in mobile app. Server don't validate it, it sends it to the social network server and do authentication if success then server get users info (register new user or update existing user's info if needed) and then creates new user session for mobile client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token that you are speaking about is not generated in the mobile app. It is generated in the 3rd-party authentication servers and passed to your mobile app. Your mobile app has to pass it back to the servers to validate your apps's authorization.

Regarding security of the token, assuming that you are using SSL, you can pass the token in either a query parameter as you suggest or as a message header. The `Authorization` header is the standard one to use, but, as you own both the mobile app and your server, you can put it in any header.

My preference is to never put anything that needs to be kept secure in a query parameter. URLs have a nasty habit of getting exposed via logs or other mechanisms. So I prefer using the header.

When you communicate with the 3rd-party servers like Google, you'll have to use whatever mechanism they require.

Comment: I meant that I'm getting access_token on the mobile client, it generates on the 3rd-party servers as you said.